# Oracle SQL Developer how to get top value

Tags: sql, oracle

I order the column from max repeats to min. But I only want to get the top value. The value that repeats the most.

This is code:

```
 SELECT foreign_key
 FROM all_person
 GROUP BY foreign_key
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

And this is what I get:

```
foreign_key
--------------
        10 
         9 
         2 
         4 
         8 
         3 
         7 
         6 
         1 
         5
```

I only want to get value 10 (in this example).
I saw alot of times that people use LIMIT but I get and error if I use LIMIT like that:

```
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

And this is error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
```

Comment: `LIMIT` is how one would do this in MySQL but won't work in Oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `ROWNUM`:

```
SELECT foreign_key FROM (
   SELECT foreign_key
     FROM all_person
    GROUP BY foreign_key
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
) WHERE rownum = 1;
```

That is the fastest way but might not work for more complex queries.

Comment: Is it possible to create variable in Oracle to sotre that number 10 in some variable? @David Faber

Comment: That's a pretty broad question, could you be more specific?

Comment: It depends on what you are doing. You can create a package and procedures/functions to return that value. You can also declare a variable and: SELECT foreign_key INTO variable_name FROM...

Answer (score 2):

You can use ROWNUM in a where clause:

```
SELECT foreign_key
FROM
(
 SELECT foreign_key
 FROM all_person
 GROUP BY foreign_key
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: Is it possible to create variable in Oracle to sotre that number 10 in some variable? @gmiley

Answer (score 2):

The `rownum` method has already been described, and it works in general.  In Oracle 12+, you can use `fetch first 1 row only`:

```
SELECT foreign_key
FROM all_person
GROUP BY foreign_key
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

You don't specify the version of Oracle you are using.  If the latest, then this will work.  This is also standard and works on some other databases.

Comment: Is it possible to create variable in Oracle to sotre that number 10 in some variable? @Gordon Linoff